# MySQL scheduled events not working on newly-added data

Tags: mysql, mariadb, insert, scheduled-tasks

I can get a scheduled event to perform calculations on a current table. But it won't perform calculations on any new rows that are added to the table. How can I get the event to use the current contents of a table?

`CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS calculation ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND STARTS '2021-01-01 00:00:00' DO SET @c = 0; SET @c = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable); SET @rownum:= 0; UPDATE myTable SET rank = (100 / @c) * (@rownum:= 1 + @rownum) ORDER BY other_column DESC LIMIT 100000;`

Comment: *But it won't perform calculations on any new rows that are added to the table.* If insertion transaction was not committed then another connection in which the event is executed cannot see them (until dirty reads allowed, of course). So commit the inserting transaction, and the rows become visible/accessible.

Comment: how do I commit them?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the `CREATE` statement for the scheduled event? This will make it much easier to offer specific suggestions rather than guessing

Comment: I just ran `SELECT @@autocommit` and it came back with the result of 1. So I gather that means it's already on.

Comment: Isn't this a super super basic question? What are people doing with their databases if not performing a few basic calculations here and there? What is MySQL even for? A static table of data to be occasionally queried? I can create my entire database in excel in about 4 minutes but somehow it takes more like 4 days to create it in MySQL and I still cant even get it to do basic things. Please someone help this is beyond ridiculous.

Comment: Apparently select statements will only work on data in a table that existed before the select statement was created. If I want the select statement to grab updated data live I need to select it from a view instead of a table.

Comment: What creates the data being processed? Create and commit some test data and see if that's processed!

Comment: I'm just creating the test data manually in HeidiSQL. What do you mean by commit? As if it's a function or something? As far as I can tell inserted data is automatically committed.

Comment: The saga continues - I'm trying to now create a 'view' so my select statements work with current data (i.e. including anything that was added after writing the scheduled events). I have the option of choosing either "Undefined" or "Merge" or "Temptable" as the "Algorithm". Undefined will make the program decide, merge allows me to use current values and temptable doesn't. Merge it is!! Oh wait, merge doesn't allow use of aggregate functions, such as COUNT(), which is what I require. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49929277/11930305. So basically I have to either use a stored procedure or subquery?

Comment: The first thing that I would do is to run **all** your commands from the `mysql` client - that's the gold standard! Although I am wondering why you're running this query every 5 seconds - perhaps if you explained what you are doing and why - with table structures (`SHOW CREATE TABLE xyz\G`) and more detail...

Comment: See also the same query in stackoverflow.